Question in the proof of the Riesz Representation theorem (locally compact Hausdorff case)
I'm reading the proof of  Riesz Representation theorem (1.5.14) in Leon Simon's book: Geometric Measure Theory
Previously I've shown that $|L(fe_{j})|\leq \int_{X}|f|d\mu=\|f\|_{L^{1}(\mu)}$ for all $f\in C_{c}(X,\mathbb{R})$. Since $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff space, the Riesz representation theorem for $L^{1}(\mu)$ works. But then I got stuck on the highlighted part.
My question: Is $\widehat{\nu}\in L^1(\mu)?$ I think the answer is NO since it didn't assume $\nu_{j}$ has compact support, so I couldn't understand why $\lim\int_{X}|g_{k}-\widehat{\nu}|=0$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Conclusion (discussed with Prof. Daniel Spector):
The highlighted part is a wrong argument, but we can modify $\widehat{\nu}$:
$$\tilde{\nu}=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \hat{\nu}&\mbox{if }f(x)\neq 0\\ 0& \mbox{if }f(x)= 0\end{array} \right.$$
Then $\tilde{\nu}$ has the same structure with $\widehat{\nu}$ but with a compact support. Since we use this $\tilde{\nu}$ only when we want to calculate $\int f|\nu|$, the further arguments with this modification are the same as before.
